# Run Custom App using Launchy on Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, sideloading

I've installed Launchy.apk for Google Glass to side-load my custom Glass application. When running Launchy, I get a screen on Google Glass that looks similar to this:

Launch...Glass Settings
...............Custom App Name 1
...............Custom App Name 2
...............Custom App Name 3

When pressing the touchpad on the side once, it highlights Glass Settings. If I press it again, it selects/loads Glass Settings. However, I can't scroll down to get to any of the Custom Apps I have installed... how do I scroll down or run these apps from Launchy? Swiping left or right does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build it from source so make sure you have the latest version:

https://github.com/kaze0/launchy

Also, the Settings menu is obsolete. You have to say "Ok Glass, Run an app".

Comment: Quite honestly, the version I had looked a bit simpler. I'll try to build the new version and see how it works. Do I need to add voice input to my custom app to get it to work?

Comment: No, the "Run an app" command is Launchy's voice command. It will then bring up a scrollable list of apps like it did original.

Comment: Okay, so I'm back to square one... this is basically the same menu I had before where I can't scroll down. How do I scroll down in this menu with the latest version of Launchy?

Comment: It's likely broken on the latest XE releases then I imagine. It doesn't appear to have been updated in a while...

Comment: Any tips on how to get this application side-loaded successfully then? I see you're an Android expert. :) The issue is that I have a camera that needs to be attached to Glass, so I can't have it attached to the computer at the same time to load the application directly from my IDE.

Comment: The APK is not compiled for Glass specifically you mean? If it were, you could simply add a voice trigger. If it's not, you can write a wrapper Glass app that then launches the secondary app. If you need help with that, ask a new question and tag me in it as it may also be useful for other people.

Comment: Awesome, my other question URL is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219972/glass-application-launch-without-launchy

Thanks a lot!