# Glass Application Launch without Launchy

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, google-glass, sideloading

I've written a Glass application using the Glass GDK and Eclipse, however I cannot get [Launchy](https://github.com/kaze0/launchy) (the side-loader application) working correctly. I've been told it's been broken since the last XE release.

Therefore, how do I get my application to run on Glass? I can see my application when I run the adb command:  `adb shell pm list packages`

**REQUIREMENT :** The micro USB connection must be free for an external camera that pairs with my application, therefore running it on Glass from within Eclipse is not an option.

Could someone provide a (hopefully easy) solution for this? I've heard that you can write a Glass application to launch another application, but am not sure how that's done.

Comment: Are you writing a Glass-specific app to begin with? Can you use a [voice trigger](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice)?

Comment: It is a Glass-specific app, but the application does not appear anywhere in the Glass menus. I can only see it when I use the abd command above. Would a voice trigger work for this in that case?

Comment: could you show your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Why do you need Launchy in the first place? you can just add your own voice trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an *Immersion* Glass app (versus say a [Live card](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/live-cards)), then you launch these with a voice command.

In development, you can create [an arbitrary voice trigger](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#unlisted_commands), but to deploy a Glassware, you have to [select from a predetermined list of voice commands](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/VoiceTriggers.Command) or [apply for a new one](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/voice-form) to be added to Glass.

I suggest you [read the Immersion overview](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/patterns/immersion) as it contains this information and more.

Answer (score -1):

In order for the Launchy app to be able to detect your application, you must at least declare one Activity with these parameters:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:icon="@drawable/your_icon">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Reference is here:
https://github.com/kaze0/launchy/blob/master/src/com/mikedg/android/glass/launchy/AppHelper.java#L96
https://github.com/kaze0/launchy/blob/master/src/com/mikedg/android/glass/launchy/AppHelper.java#L97

Comment: I've done this and Launchy will still not launch my app. As I mentioned in my question, I've heard from multiple sources now that it's broken with no new pushes for at least 7 months, how true that is I don't know. More importantly, the question specifically asks for a solution on how to launch the app without Launchy.

Feel free to provide a solution specific to the question and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: So you can only start your application by declaring a voice trigger as described in the  'voice section' of the gdk documentation